# Build mixed projects on Linux using MSBuild 15 fails

Tags: msbuild, mono, .net-core

Can anybody assist me with the following issue I am having? I am trying to build a mixed solution on linux using MSBuild 15. It contains projects that targets netstandard2.0 and then also projects that target .Net 4.6.2

The netstandard2.0 projects build fine, but the projects that target .Net 4.6.2 fails with the following error:

Your project.json doesn't have a runtimes section. You should add '"runtimes": { "win": { } }' to your project.json and then re-run NuGet restore

I am using MSBuild version 15.6.0.0 for Mono and running on Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 0):

quick fix: delete the `obj/` directory and then rebuild.

The best I've got at the moment is

```
rm -rf obj ; msbuild /t:restore /t:build
```